# addition of elements within an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array full of numbers which I want to add to each other.

For example, if the array is:

```
my_list =np.array([2,3,4,5,6]).
```

I want to add 3 to 2 (index 1 to 0) and the 4 to 3 (index 2 to 1) and so on.

Any help or ideas for this would be great as I'm quite new to python and coding and am rather stuck.

Comment: Can you show us where you're stuck? You'll learn more from fixing your mistakes than from copy-pasting the right solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Could you post the expected result for your `[2,3,4,5,6]` list ?

Comment: Does it have to be a while loop?

Comment: Do you have an array or a list? And why a while loop? That's pretty much the most wrong way to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples - it will give you an idea of the tools Python has to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the [`itertools` recipe pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

nums = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
sums = [a + b for a, b in pairwise(nums)]
print(sums)
# [5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Another is to use the built-in `zip`:

```
sums = [a + b for a, b in zip(nums, nums[1:])]
```

And finally, as requested in the comments by [@StefanPochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann), if you are using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
nums = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
sums = nums[:-1] + nums[1:]
```

---

As for speed, the `numpy` solution is basically unbeatable, as long as your input array is already a `numpy.array`. If not, then casting it to an array, the `zip` and the `pairwise` one are about equally fast. Tests done with Python 3.6.3.

Test input:

```
import random
x = [random.sample(range(1000), n) for n in range(1, 1000, 50)]
```

[image]

In the end, `numpy` also has `O(n)` behaviour (note that the length of the array is 100 more than before), its constant is just way lower:

[image]

Comment: @ downvoter I am happy to fix my post if there is anything wrong with it

Comment: (not the downvoter, just late to the party) I like your answer, but think the question had a bug in that since it refers to numpy the nums should already been in an array, so fixed that. Still think this answer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
nums = [2,3,4,5,6]
sums = []


for i in range(0, len(nums)):
    if(i!=0):
        sums.append(nums[i] + nums[i-1])

print(sums)
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 9, 11]
```